# Edit correctly rejected but wrongly marked as spam

Tags: discussion

[This edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/157176) was recently suggested to one of my posts. I agree that it should have been rejected; however, it was rejected as "This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive." This is, in my opinion incorrect: it is in no way promoting a product or service and is not at all destructive. My understanding is that there are fairly severe consequences to a user if their posts are marked as spam and I feel that these consequences are unwarranted in this case. Is it possible that they can be undone? (Or do they not apply to anonymous users?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Don't worry about it.**

Edits marked as spam are not posts marked as spam; penalties (if there were any) cannot be applied to an anonymous user as the system doesn't know who they are.

The edit was correctly rejected. There are a few standard reasons, and "defaces the post/deliberately destructive" which includes spam is one of them; there are other reasons which can be used, but it doesn't really matter. An anonymous user is not going to come back to see it. For this reason, it wouldn't really matter if the user *did* get the 100-rep penalty; they will never be back.

I would probably have used the "incorrect attempt to reply to the author" reason, or "alters the post against the author's intention". But it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks -- that all sounds sensible.